# Issue with SQL Query ( Booking Software )

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following fiddle.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd3e6d07208978a987503953b29a1b7e

```
CREATE TABLE shifts (
    id int NOT NULL,
    unique_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE appointments (
    id int NOT NULL,
    unique_id varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    start_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    end_date DATETIME NOT NULL,
    shift_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (shift_id) REFERENCES shifts(id)
);

INSERT INTO `shifts` (`id`, `unique_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`)
VALUES
    ('4596', '614fc0c5dab2485bba8cbbd9eb98aa53', '2022-02-28 10:00:00', '2022-03-15 19:00:00');


INSERT INTO `appointments` (`id`, `unique_id`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `shift_id`)
VALUES
    (18352, 'accdc12943954ee2bd69ad116c2fef3d', '2022-02-28 18:15:00', '2022-02-28 19:00:00', 4596),
    (18351, '6a0d56ad43894b60b4f8a289fbbfff73', '2022-02-28 17:30:00', '2022-02-28 18:15:00', 4596),
    (18545, '4a49c054e59e4514ae2a521b55a7715c', '2022-02-28 16:50:00', '2022-02-28 17:15:00', 4596),
    (18622, '02ca48b35ca3462f9030bcb97ea1dbab', '2022-02-28 16:30:00', '2022-02-28 16:50:00', 4596),
    (18544, 'd27bc7ba34a74f078966ebe1567d3181', '2022-02-28 16:00:00', '2022-02-28 16:30:00', 4596),
    (18685, '4057b87c089b463188a26bc45d85388a', '2022-02-28 15:00:00', '2022-02-28 15:10:00', 4596),
    (18462, '3270929ae6e546fb824e6d3219917b8e', '2022-02-28 14:30:00', '2022-02-28 16:00:00', 4596),
    (18235, 'deac969701ae47f0a78696f12c267475', '2022-02-28 14:00:00', '2022-02-28 14:30:00', 4596),
    (18540, 'e16af8a053594e8b8340ede302398a22', '2022-02-28 13:30:00', '2022-02-28 14:00:00', 4596),
    (18537, 'e1946add03cd412da357b58c93d58c6e', '2022-02-28 12:30:00', '2022-02-28 13:15:00', 4596),
    (18355, 'ec570f9365bb4ad68c7b5ab3b7d9aeea', '2022-02-28 12:00:00', '2022-02-28 12:30:00', 4596),
    (18523, 'aff5abe6e8f84a64ace3277d3cd6dbd1', '2022-02-28 11:00:00', '2022-02-28 12:00:00', 4596),
    (18517, '124baaa1aeab421cb288f2b7c7abe89b', '2022-02-28 10:30:00', '2022-02-28 11:00:00', 4596),
    (18382, '1371e41a7cf342bfa279a8b120cc5f43', '2022-02-28 10:00:00', '2022-02-28 10:30:00', 4596);



SELECT Available_from, Available_to
  FROM (
    SELECT COALESCE(@lasttime_to, '2022-02-28 10:00:00') AS Available_from, start_date AS Available_to, @lasttime_to := end_date
    FROM (SELECT start_date, end_date
             FROM appointments
             WHERE end_date <= '2022-02-28 19:00:00'
             AND start_date >= '2022-02-28 10:00:00'
             UNION ALL (
               SELECT '2022-02-28 19:00:00', '2022-02-28 19:00:00'
             )
             UNION ALL (
               SELECT '2022-02-28 10:00:00', '2022-02-28 10:00:00'
             )
               ORDER BY start_date, end_date
           ) e
    JOIN (SELECT @lasttime_to := NULL) init) x
    WHERE Available_to > DATE_ADD(Available_from, INTERVAL 14 MINUTE);
```

How can I make this query ignore edge cases such as the one?

```
2022-02-28 13:15:00 2022-02-28 13:30:00
2022-02-28 15:10:00 2022-02-28 16:00:00 ( EDGE CASE )
2022-02-28 17:15:00 2022-02-28 17:30:00
```

This is caused by the appointment which lasts from

```
'2022-02-28 15:00:00' TO '2022-02-28 15:10:00'
```

IDEAL RESULT:

```
2022-02-28 13:15:00 2022-02-28 13:30:00
2022-02-28 17:15:00 2022-02-28 17:30:00
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.x you should use a window function rather than `@lasttime_to`

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by edge case? What is this query supposed to be doing, and why shouldn't that row be included?

Comment: Well this query should take the free time slots for the day. And it says that 16 is a free time slot however it's not there is an appointment in that time

Comment: Appointments in your sample vary in length , so how long is a time slot how are they assigned and if an appointment doesn't match a multiple of timeslots do you pad it out?

Comment: The appointment can be from one minute to let's say 8 hours so free will

Comment: Then how is that a timeslot??

Comment: I don't get it...  it's a slot of time... It takes an interval of time

Comment: You would think that a vacant 'slot' could be identified by checking the difference between start_date and end_date BUT your sample as presented appears to be in no specific order and if ordered by id then there are overlaps resulting in negative differences using this algorithm for example id 18352 as an end_date of '2022-02-28 19:00:00' and 18355 has a start time of '2022-02-28 12:00:00' resulting in -7 hours. Is there a problem with your sample? Or something you haven't told us?

Comment: The id is not relevant the start and end_date are.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timestamp tally of all minutes in the interval in question to find free minutes and them group them into available intervals.

```
with t1(c) as (
   select 0 union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
), dtally as (
   select  TIMESTAMPADD(minute, row_number() over() - 1, '2022-02-28 10:00:00') t,  row_number() over() rn
   from t1, t1 as t2, t1 as t3, t1 as t4
), freeMins as ( 
   select *, rn - row_number() over(order by rn)  grp
   from dtally
   where t <= '2022-02-28 19:00:00'
   and not exists (
          select 1 
          from appointments a
          where t between a.start_date and a.end_date)
)
select min(t) Available_from, max(t) Available_to
from freeMins
group by grp
```

Returns

```
Available_from  Available_to
2022-02-28 13:16:00 2022-02-28 13:29:00
2022-02-28 17:16:00 2022-02-28 17:29:00
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58b6ea90cc55cb4ff212ecf63d1c99bb)

Comment: This works on the data i sent but check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a789538c0e5f48fba254019b321de95a . Doesn't work on this

Comment: @FilipStojkovski,  your fiddle  INSERT has the wrong  `shift_id` column name. It works when corrected.

Comment: @FilipStojkovski , when working with a MySql fiddle I advice every batch has exactly one statement. Otherwise some errors could pass undetected.

Comment: This is working to be honest, i would just like to know why in t1 there is 9 selects.

Comment: @FilipStojkovski, 10 really. 10 rows cross joined  4 times produce 10**4 rows in the `dtally` cte. If you need more just add more cross joins to the cte.